# Copyright vs Translations

Tags: united-states, copyright, translation

An author writes,

> He slew the unicorn.

I can't legally quote that without permission, but I could write "He said he killed the unicorn."

In that spirit, imagine you want to quote a passage in a book that's published in French. If you translate it into English, it will have the same meaning, but the words will be different.

Would this be legal?

Comment: Replacing the word "slay" with "kill" is unlikely to help, nor is translating it to another language. Generally short quotes like this are allowed as fair use or fair dealing. The short example you've shown might even be seen as a statement of fact. Although it's fiction, what we have here is a statement of fact that a particular character slew a particular unicorn in a particular story.